Error while "pre-commit run" command: "No matching distribution found for types-pkg-resources"
python: 3.10
Error while "pre-commit run" command: "No matching distribution found for types-pkg-resources" that dependency package for types-all that have only one version. I know that "types-pkg-resources" already yanked, but project already have it.
I tried manually download package then install. But it did not help, because pre-commit try to install all packages from scratch.
Is there a way to set configs to ignore only one package from types-all (not all of them with "--no-deps", there are many other packages to install separately). Or maybe ignore this step in pre-commit? because there are many ways to install yanked version of package to the project.
